# Why is my function returning the wrong type

Tags: python, types

I have a stack of child classes:
Matrix, which I downloaded.

Quaternion, which extends the Matrix class

```
class Quaternion(Matrix):  #initializes to unit quaternion. 
    def __init__(self, a = 1.0, b = 0.0, c = 0.0, d = 0.0):
        super().__init__(4,1)
        self[1,1] = a
        self[2,1] = b
        self[3,1] = c
        self[4,1] = d
# ... with a bunch of functions
```

and Vector, which extends Quaternion.

```
class Vector(Quaternion):  
    #default, initializes to null vector 
    def __init__(self, a = 0.0, b = 0.0, c = 0.0, d = 0.0):
```

So far, so good.
The problem is that in my `Vector.__add__` function

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        q2 = Vector()
        print(q2.__class__) #debug
        q2 = Matrix.__add__(self, other)
        print(q2.__class__)
        return q2
```

The first `print(q2.__class__)` returns `<class '__main__.Vector'>` like it should.
But, after the addition line, which calls the Matrix addition function: `q2 = Matrix.__add__(self, other)`
the second `print(q2.__class__)` returns `<class 'matrix.matrix.Matrix'>`.

Huh? `q2` is specifically defined as a vector. Even if I call the matrix addition, why is it now a Matrix - two classes up the chain? This messes things up, because when I try something like

```
v3 = Vector()
v3 = v1.get_translate(v2)  # (which uses the __add__ function)
q1 = Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1)
q1.angle_to_quaternion(math.radians(30.0))
v4 = v3.rotate(q1)
```

the error comes back

```
AttributeError: 'Matrix' object has no attribute 'rotate'
```

because `v3` is now a Matrix, not a Vector.

How do I convince the function to not change the type?

This behavior is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: We need to see the `Matrix.__add__()` method, but it sounds like it calls `Matrix()` to create the return value.

Comment: All the `__add__()` methods need to ensure that the return value is the same class as `self`, which may not be the same as the class that they're defined in, it could be a subclass.

Comment: The fact that the first thing you assigned to `q2` was a `Vector` doesn't mean everything else you assign to it will be a `Vector` too.

Comment: "Even if I call the matrix addition, why is it now a Matrix - two classes up the chain?" presumably because *you* defined `Matrix.__add__` to return a `Matrix`. We can only speculate without a [mcve]

Comment: "This behavior is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation." In *what* documentation?

Comment: @juanpa *"you defined `Matrix.__add__` to return a Matrix"* -- They said at the top that they downloaded it. I'm assuming it's optimized like CPython `int`, i.e. hard-coded in certain ways, which makes subclassing difficult.

Comment: "Huh? q2 is specifically defined as a vector." - **No, it is not. There are no type definitions in Python.** "Even if I call the matrix addition, why is it now a Matrix - two classes up the chain?" - what do you suppose should happen instead? You want the `Matrix` that was returned from that class' own addition method, to become a `Vector` - how, exactly? How should the `Matrix` class know anything about your `Vector` class, such as how to construct one? "How do I convince the function to not change the type?" On the contrary; you are trying to convince it **to** change the type.

Comment: No, I was assuming that like C++, if I declare a variable as type Vector and call a Matrix add operation on it, it performs the actual add function on the Matrix portion of the Vector class, but doesn't change anything about the actual variable. Obviously, this is not how Python works. Which begs the question, why not? That's the whole purpose of class inheritance! Yes, of course Matrix __add__ returns a Matrix. It shouldn't, not for a child class of Matrix.

Comment: Keep in mind that _type declarations in Python are only advisory_. They're used for static checking of code, but they don't change anything about how code _actually works_ at runtime (except in absence of software that explicitly performs introspection). But your code isn't even setting _advisory_ type hints; you have no types declared at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `q2` is specifically defined as a vector.

That's not how Python works. The name `q2` does not carry a type, it's more like a labelled bucket that holds a reference to whatever you assign to it. Whether that's a `Vector` or a `Matrix`, Python doesn't care, and doesn't cast anything for you.

- More info: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder

If you can't edit `Matrix`, then you'll need to do the conversion yourself, maybe like this:

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        mat = Matrix.__add__(self, other)
        q2 = type(self).from_matrix(mat)
        return q2
```

I'm supposing you have a `Vector.from_matrix` classmethod for the sake of example, but you'll know better than me how to actually convert a `Matrix` to a `Vector` in your code.

And I'm using `type(self)` so that you can avoid the same problem in your code, i.e. so that child classes can return values of their own type. In other words (using type hinting):

```
    def __add__(self: T, other: T) -> T:
```

not:

```
    def __add__(self: T, other: T) -> Vector:
```

Comment: P.S. I have very little experience with low-level stuff or other languages, so please correct me if I've got any details wrong.

Comment: P.P.S. Should I mention `super()`?

Comment: "I'm supposing you have a Vector.from_matrix classmethod " What's that? Of course I don't! (what would one look like?) I've figured out super(), thanks.

Comment: In C++, which is where I'm coming from, a name is a pointer to the actual data structure. Let's say I have object X of class B which is a child class of A. If I call X.function() where function() is defined for class A, the compiler knows the relationships and function() only operates on the parts of X that originate in class A. The fundamental problem here seems to be that when Matrix does the addition, it creates a new Matrix and passes it back, replacing the value of V1. So, as you said, I need that Vector.fromMatrix function of yours.

Comment: Ok, that worked. I defined
     @classmethod
    def from_matrix(cls, m1: Matrix):
        q1 = Quaternion(m1[1,1], m1[2,1], m1[3,1], m1[4,1])
        return(q1)

and now 
    def __add__ (self, q1):
        m1 = Matrix.__add__(self, q1)
        q2 = type(self).from_matrix(m1)
        return q2
returns the right type.
Thank you!

Comment: @PaulBlase `Quaternion()`? That's close to what I meant, but, like I'm using `type(self)`, you should be using `cls` there. Are you sure it's returning the correct type? Cause that makes it look like `Vector.__add__` will return a `Quaternion`.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your `Matrix.__add__()` method. You're probably creating a Matrix instance in your Matrix.**add** method and returning it, which you don't want.

You'd want your `matrix.__add__` method to take two args (obj1 and obj2) -> do something with obj1 and obj2 -> return updated version of obj1 (or obj2)...

Also, if written right, you can just call q1 + q2 (or self + other) and get the result you want - you may not even need to create a `vector.__add__()`. Unless, your intent is to override what `Quaternion.__add__()` is doing. We need to see what `matrix.__add__()` is doing though if you want more feedback.

As for python's behavior, python is dynamically typed meaning the type of variable could change during run time. So `q2 = Vector()` doesn't mean `q2` is exclusively a vector class.

Other programming language requires you to declare a type before using a variable (static typing). Not python.

Everything in Python is an object (or you can think of is as, everything is a pointer).